# Short description block is not avaliable in magento. Didn't found how to enable it

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system

I want to enable products short description in product page, but I`ve stucked. Theme package - Ultimo. In admin panel I set the property “Used in product listing” to “Yes”, but still it doesn't show my short description.I have only this code in view.phtm file.

```
<?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
            <div class="short-description">
                <h2><?php echo $this->__('Quick Overview') ?></h2>
                <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
            </div>
        <?php endif;?>
```

Can anyone show me direction where should I take ?

Answer (score 0):

Just to eliminate the possibility that the short description isn't loaded, add a first line of PHP to your snippet:

```
<?php  $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId()); ?>
```

What does Ultimo have in its `view.phtml`?